# What happens to all the items in lists on a closed board?

Tags: trello

I closed a board by mistaken.  When I reopened it, it had all of its lists, but every list was empty; every item that I wanted to keep track of in Trello has apparently been deleted.  Is there a way to get them back?

Comment: The same thing happened to me today BUT after a while all the cards appeared again. I guess it is solved.

Comment: Does a refresh help? The browser may have forgot about the cards and forgot to check.